# Packing binary data to source-safe ascii efficiently

Tags: code-challenge

## Description

Here's a challenge with a somewhat practical use, at least for us golfers.

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to write a program that can take arbitrary binary data (either from stdin, or a file) and output some valid source code which provides access to the data. The generator and target languages need not be the same.

## Scoring

Your program will be run against two inputs: a 1 KiB file of random characters, and the lyrics of Never Gonna Give You Up by Rick Astley.  The program with the lowest score wins. Your score is calculated as follows:

> (**A** + **B**) × log<sub>e</sub>(**Z**)

Where:

- **A** is the number of bytes in the output for the random data;
- **B** is the number of bytes in the output for Never Gonna Give You Up; and
- **Z** is the number of useful bytes in the target programming language *(useful is a very broad definition and may be refined in the future)*

For example:

- in C++ the generally allowed characters are `"\t \r\nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!\"#%&'()*+,-./:;<=?[\\]^_{|}~"` which would give **Z** = 94
- in Brainfuck the only non-ignored characters are `"<>+-.,[]"` which gives **Z** = 8

## Examples

Two examples in Python, both generating python source:

*Python allows files encoded in UTF-16, so the valid python bytes are from 0x00-0xFF*

#### Using Repr

```
import sys
print 'data=',repr(sys.stdin.read())
```

Score: (2898 + 2098) × log<sub>e</sub>(256) = 27,704

#### Using Base64

```
import sys
from base64 import b64encode
print 'from base64 import b64decode;data=b64decode("'+b64encode(sys.stdin.read())+'")'
```

Score: (1416 + 2640) × log<sub>e</sub>(256) = 22,491

## Data

The data is given here encoded in base64, these files should be decoded prior to passing to your program.  The decoding is outside of the scope of this challenge.

#### Random

```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==
```

#### Never Gonna Give You Up

```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```

Comment: @PeterTaylor Excellent point, I'll update it.

Comment: Voting to close because "useful" is very vague, especially for something so important to answers' scores.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP 8986

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('php://stdin');
printf('$var=gzuncompress(base64_decode("%s"));', base64_encode(gzcompress($data)));
```

#### Binary 1417

```
$var=gzuncompress(base64_decode("eJwBAAT/+9pqBPAhkAkkq/FeLh2nijL7SVLUralcL4J98RoAliJUVmhI1Uy5hf359IXl2IexiDwFEmZhGtqUeSk7i3y1bTzIvHlIOfdN83f2+ewSFSRDxlTsgYc8Rk5c2BFRt7mlMJ0jpacPcz+Uiv74wzQwnReCCWQYPHB5aGqMasNQZt9Ohler+vxs8fjB3AjrFMk9DMqjgIG7gOLeevEE0/Ns3f522UNgRPUOm5iMKLXwQkz8FdE0oXrQrn8WSQW51azZQ1vAQ5yjBs6sLP3SU/gtN53XeuLLM4/0Lr64u+BGq34Ov9O3mhoeSmPKJzIaUYgf5PzOmh6QP4JZmhTRORrtE7ClYDQh1Aj9Q6m/TCkdxVNtQ4OnzbbUeJvmSTbW1MjMup1k7gcfze4XFFyHZ+RRel+a/hHVLScVdaXoGgz7CjtVnmoNU0+RaniBRCssNi/TV+0ALF7r2vGP+v/ohB/5XSBHv2R8z3OZKj7boqepf8tvs5Xly8O1uI0Nbyy9MWyOCdJUIaS54gnNSvuevfUzfPpNNQteiXUkHxAMfnVZUaupvVX9LlqJ1FoK2LJr7WOIZgtQKigyK/aeqwes0S93f/HLR3isC2ZZoRwkGKsmVEYsVSZzpGpiJPCT+sZPNpQtz8gnz/X8B4rYLsCuC58+sdtrJ6h75PH1vYmW8nVo4xVtfkl9ihOTOKa+0irPls2xlpLPRWTaB5RheCbta0/M5WFlMF/96mdoRyrnPrV8HnW++b4/DQ3k4gQIA/9y93JLfF8NCchSgl795wicd6wu6ANcdVO2XsJUE4AoqT5FK0RXoSmAozONofFwo9cla27i+X077mS+Uf8TgC8/FytMsT6jeVoFLQ+FBXMbJrwGejq2xcrHIrneYTR5GZa/U69qFLRb7cfKOnlh/3hztziRcioinagxP0c8J2j3jQ/Q2mdwNiZ/+US/iB31kZQOUPYuaZToOr92TLhoTyV+7X6o7VVu8+Tp0aU2dr6QzFcFlHcoA25o14OsSBblWc10foXaBd3Rm9IgTpDpbLwEjZ5i7PmUoCRWHtN8nYxXvAlRvA6IIuwmvRbWhrznpvDKrI1UtrBw3S2kOgB19MtxxL4Svjt7nQKE87SG/1SC8mgPTVZ8cIiuTAnXwZdAh5UcZldqA2GscWufFNpZRKp/WnXE3af3h/0FYX7t9vnNceKTDAz2cRvRwbTnuaCBRD1GLYes87bQ/5n2tFUTzPmWtTlqWvkqRbFfLKWHN/HPXebfMdooTX9gdLzf7fGN0dIHvIqup/07dhBgUaKe8Vb9NdzjMuVFAO6ohnsSL+MUtjlFvIElG8MbdmvvEOVkAcNS1Oxi0+pg7Gb0Pr7B6ot+DznCPnHYlQQF"));
```

#### ASCII 561

```
$var=gzuncompress(base64_decode("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"));
```

#### Z 94

Assumed the same character set as given for C++ in the question.

There's not really much wiggle room on how to accomplish this aside from compression and base64 encoding. The only "step up" I can think of would be finagling base128 encoding, but there aren't enough "safe" characters to accomplish this given the variability of extended-ASCII.

Comment: is the output in php? then it is not valid source without at least `<? `

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby

Long version:

```
require 'tempfile'
tf=Tempfile.new('r')
while $stdin.gets{tf.puts $_}
tf.rewind
print "data='"
print IO.read(tf).gsub(/'/,"\\'")
print "'"
```

Golfed-up version

```
require 'tempfile'
t=Tempfile.new('r');while gets{t.puts $_};t.rewind;p "data='"+IO.read(t).gsub(/'/,"\\'")+"'"
```

Comment: When I run this on either input, I just get 'data=' followed by the raw binary, which doesn't work in Ruby.

Comment: @tecywiz121 you're right, modified to put the binary between "'"

Comment: What if the data contains a single quote?

Comment: @tecywiz121 I suppose it matters (though none of the test data, as binary, should contain a plaintext single quote), so I added a `gsub(/'/,"\\'")`